# In Jmeter API Testing,i want one http sampler to use header manager of its own and other http sampler in Test plan to use a common header manager

Tags: performance, jmeter, header, http-headers, web-api-testing

i have a test plan that has 50 http sampler ( API testing )
i want 1 http sampler to use header manager of its own(i.e. specefic to the sampler) and other 49 to use global header manager (common) ( i dont want to add header manager for every http sampler)

attached image
Login request has its own header manager , when i add a global header manager , login sampler takes both global header details and its own header details
how can i make login sampler to use only headers from its child header manager and not common ?

[image: 1]

How can i make http samplers to use headers of its own( child or same level) and not common
or how can i override the common header manager ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager):

> JMeter now supports multiple Header Managers. The **header entries are merged to form the list for the sampler**. If an entry to be merged matches an existing header name, it replaces the previous entry. This allows one to set up a default set of headers, and apply adjustments to particular samplers. Note that an empty value for a header does not remove an existing header, it justs replace its value.

So there is only **one** HTTP Header Manager containing combined headers from the top-level one and with the one which is the child of the current sampler.

If you want to remove all headers which are set by the top-level header manager - you need to add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and do it there. New headers can be added in the same JSR223 PreProcessor if needed.

Example code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header

sampler.getHeaderManager().clear()
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header('header1','value1'))
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header('header2','value2'))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)